# How to manipulate only weights of neural network when biases are intact using Pytorch?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, pytorch

In the following `for` loop I get `name`'s and `parameter`'s of my neural network. Depending on the bias flag I will do some operations on the `weight`'s and `bias`'s using `block` after 'if' and 'elif'. However, when `bias` is `False`, I just do operations on `weight`'s but if `bias` flag is `True`, I will do it for both `weight`'s and `bias`'s.

```py
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if bias = Fasle and 'weight' in name:
        weight_np = param.data.cpu().numpy()
        alive = weight_np[np.nonzero(weight_np)] # extract nonzero values
        percentile_value = np.percentile(abs(alive), percent)

        # Convert Tensors to numpy and calculate
        weight_dev = param.device
        new_mask = np.where(abs(weight_np) < percentile_value, 0, mask[step])
    elif bias = True and 'weight' or 'bias' in name:
        weight_np = param.data.cpu().numpy()
        alive = weight_np[np.nonzero(weight_np)] # extract nonzero values
        percentile_value = np.percentile(abs(alive), percent)

        # Convert Tensors to numpy and calculate
        weight_dev = param.device
        new_mask = np.where(abs(weight_np) < percentile_value, 0, mask[step])
```

**Question**: since `block` is the same for `if` and `elif`, I want to avoid writing it and have it once. Can you help me to figure this out?

Comment: Please show the `**block**` or describe what it does. If it's the same in both cases then the `if` and `elif` are not needed?

Comment: @Andreas K: I added the block.